# How I can add image on top of email on opencart order add file&

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I have the following line of code

```
$data['logo'] = $order_info['store_url'] . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
```

Which includes the logo on top of my email. Now I want to add another image, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively easy:

1. Duplicate that line of code,
2. Rename `$data['logo']` to something that makes sense for your needs e.g. `$data['other_image']`,
3. Change `$this->config->get('config_logo');` to the filename of the image bearing in mind that the image must be in the `public_html/image` folder.

Make sure you reference the new variable `{{other_image}}` in the appropriate `.twig` file.